# How to poll input for a gui in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Ok, so my question is simple. How do you poll input with a GUI class without it affecting what's underneath the GUI? So suppose you have an RPG game with a gui for the d-pad and other controls:

```
gui.getInput(); //User taps button in the gui
world.getInput(); //The tap should have only affected the gui, but instead goes through and also affects the world
```

How can you deal with this problem? I thought of some ways but I don't like them.

Comment: Why does `world` have a `getInput()` method? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @congusbongus well thats not the point but its for the player or something. Its an example

Comment: You could just have a Boolean that is set true if gui input fires and then skips world input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me look into [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). 
It handles everything input related for you.
You can even do timed based actions on it, which are very nice.
**Its also built into libGDX.**
Truuuuust me its super easy once you get the hang of it.
Honestly, I now write everything in Scene2D.

If your having issues getting started with it, Heres a little sample code for you

```
 Stage stage;
    ImageButton title; //(there are several types of these, even just simply Image)
    InputListener titleListen; //(also several variants)


 ///----------------------------------------
    //init phase
            stage = new Stage();
            stage.setViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //important


            titleListen = new InputListener(){
    //many different types of inputs to override
                @Override
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                        int pointer, int button) {
                    //something
                    return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
                }

            };




    ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
            style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(assets.title); //has to be a textureregion
            style.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(assets.title);
            title = new ImageButton(style);
            title.setSize(title.getWidth()*assets.scaleX, title.getHeight()*assets.scaleY);
            title.setPosition(whereever);
            stage.addActor(title);//adds it to the Scene
            play.addListener(titleListen); //adds the listener

  ///----------------------------------------  
    //game loop
//
//
//
    stage.act(delta); //updates Scene and grabs inputs

    stage.draw(); //draws Scene
```

Comment: Thanks I think I'll use it. I was looking for input multiplexer

Comment: Scene2D is very nice!

Comment: I love how you can use virtual joysticks and buttons and scroll bars and everything that a ui should have. It seems very useful!